# Laravel - provider class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know there's been numerous other posts like this, but none of them worked for me, and I'm at my rope's end - this is driving me nuts.

I'm using [CloudConvert](https://github.com/robbiepaul/cloudconvert-laravel), which works perfectly on my local instance. When pushing up to my EC2 server, I'm just getting this error:

```
Class 'CloudConvert' not found in /var/www/html/api/app/Jobs/UploadFile.php:169
```

I've obviously tried `composer dump-autoload` which does nothing, tried `composer update` and `composer install` which did even less. I've removed any record of it, re-installed with `composer require` and then `php artisan vendor:publish`. Also nothing. Gave `php artisan optimize --force` but that's never really worked for anything.

I'm adding the service provider like so:

```
RobbieP\CloudConvertLaravel\CloudConvertLaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

...and the facade like so:

```
'CloudConvert' => RobbieP\CloudConvertLaravel\Facades\CloudConvert::class,
```

Once again, works perfectly locally. I'm sort of out of ideas.

Anyone got any insights I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear your config? `php artisan config:clear`.

Sometimes it also helps to delete the cached files in `bootstrap/cache/*.php`.

Comment: I've tried both of those too - didn't seem to help. I've also tried including with `use RobbieP\CloudConvertLaravel\Facades\CloudConvert as CloudConvert;` instead of the facade, same deal.

Comment: @MitchEff what happens if you remove the cached files, the vendor folder, then run `composer install` and call the required action?
Does it have artisan actions you can call? If so, is the output as expected or does it throw the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's not a solution per se, but restarting my whole server seemed to fix it.

No idea at all why, but I guess it's got nothing to do with caches or anything...